# Can't run Java Spring app on Java 6. Says it needs JDK 1.5 or Later

Tags: java, spring, maven, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run an old Spring app on my Tomcat 9.0 server through VSCode. I successfully created the WAR and attempted to run it, only to be met with the following error.

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/SiteAdmin-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context namespace element 'annotation-config' and its parser class [org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigBeanDefinitionParser] are only available on JDK 1.5 and higher

After doing some research, I found that the Spring version i'm using is an old one, that doesn't recognize Java versions above 7. I tried downloading Java 6 to fix this, but it still gives me the same error when I try to run it.

I should mention, the Java plugin for VSCode only functions if you have jdk 11 or higher, so that's the main one I have, but I set the compiler target for the war to be at 1.6, as well as the JAVA_HOME variable for Tomcat. I even set the main system path variables to point at Java 6.

Despite this, running the Java -version command gives me version 11. Even VSCode recognizes it as Java 1.6.

Any help or advice in getting past this error would be greatly appreciated. If you need any more info, please let me know.

I should also mention, i'm running this on a Windows 10 machine.

UPDATE: I should also mention that I have tried editing the properties as well, both the compiler and the maven properties were set to 1.6, the version i'm trying to run. It still gives me the same error.

Comment: Tomcat 9 expects jdk8 or later, see http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Answer (score 2):

Keep Jdk11 as `java.home` both in system and vscode, then like [@Nathan Hughes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217324/nathan-hughes)'s comment, Tomcat9 needs jdk8 or higher version. Choose `JDK11` to be **Project JDKs** and **Java Tooling Runtime**, then `clean java language server worksapce` from Command Palette. Rebuild projects and see if the error goes away:

[image]

Comment: when I try to generate the WAR file with the project JDK set to 11. it says that package com.sun.jndi.ldap is not visible. It uses it for more than just obtaining the String, so I can't just get rid of the dependency.

Comment: @CalebBoard. Delete and reinstall it from **Command Palette**-> Maven: Add a dependency-> search `com.sun.jndi.ldap` and readd it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set java version properties

```
<properties>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Or to configure maven-compiler-plugin

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Here configuring for Java 8. Default is set to Java 6 since Maven 3.

Have a Look at https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

Comment: i've already tried that, I set the source and target values to 1.6